# Way to prevent line breaks "\n" "\r" from being removed?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I seem to be running into a problem where user input in a text area includes a line break (user starting a new paragraph) and I have their input sanitized with real_escape_string and inserted into a MySQL database. Problem is, those line breaks are not retained. Instead it becomes one looong paragraph.

I am running PHP version 7.2.4, and I've tried to recreate the problem to see if it's some existing code that is causing the problem. What typically has worked for others does not seem to be doing the trick for me, like str_replace and nl2br

```
if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
  $content = $_POST['content'];

  $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);

  echo "real escaped: " . $content;

  $content = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $content);

  echo "str_replaced" . $content;

  echo (nl2br($content, false));

  $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `stories` (`post_id`, `content`) VALUES (NULL, '{$content}')";
                   // INSERT INTO `stories` (`post_id`, `content`) VALUES (NULL, 'egdhfhj')

  $insert_post = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_query);

  if(!$insert_post) {
    die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($conn));
  } else {
    echo "Posted successfully";
  }

}

echo "Current posts";

$read_query = "SELECT * FROM stories";

$display_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $read_query);

if (!$display_posts) {
  die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($conn));
} else {

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display_posts)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $content = $row['content'];

    echo "<p>" . $post_id . "<p>";
    echo "<p>" . $content . "<p>";
  }
}
?>
```

Basically, my goal is to take the exact typed format in the way of line breaks and print them out exactly the way they are entered. Currently with my form, if you type in:

```
This is one line.
This is the next.
```

It prints out "this is one line. this is the next" from the database entry.

I have several echoes in my script (as you can see) and each one prints 
"This is my first line\r\nThis is the next" every time. None of my functions are working. Am I doing this right?

P.S. I'm super new to PHP and MySQL so I won't be surprised if it's syntax errors, but I swear I have looked and everything looks correct from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid executing mysqli_real_escape_string altogether and the danger of SQL injection (please investigate this topic) by using a **prepared statement**:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `stories` (`post_id`, `content`) VALUES (NULL, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli_prepare($conn, $insert_query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $content); /* "s" means this is a string parameter */
mysqli_execute($stmt);
mysqli_close($stmt);
```

Comment: OP wants to  input in a text area includes a line break into database , after that retrieves from that as it is .

Comment: @MohitKumar First of all, it was not I who downvoted you. Why would you make that assumption? Second, my solution preserves carriage returns, linefeeds and whatever other characters may be in the input. It does so more safely than solutions that do not use prepared statements. I would suggest that you, too, investigate SQL injection and prepared statements.

Comment: @MohitKumar If you look at the code above with any care, you can see that variable $content is taken from $_POST['content'] and is unmodified in any way before being bound to the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nl2br()` function in PHP. it will preserve your aspects.